# how can I export a portion of ios app as sdk or library

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

I want to export a view with a couple of UI elements as a standalone library/SDK.
I have been able to achieve this in android by exporting an app as .aar , then importing it as library and calling the respective Activity through intent.
I am fairly new to iOS (and swift) and I wanted to check if something like this is possible. if yes then how.
For context I specifically want to call an "Activity" from library/SDK which loads a hardcoded webview.

Thanks in advance. please mention any lack of information needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible in iOS as well. You can follow one of the following tutorials to achieve that:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_standalone_swift_package_with_xcode
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios